# Need to stop jPlayer on main page when popup player is initiated

Tags: popup, jplayer

I am using the CirclePlayer and it starts automatically when the particular page is loaded. The player has a popup option and I need to stop the player on the main window and allow only the popup window player to play.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
    {
        '.$streamtype.': "'.$stream.'",
    }, {
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
        swfPath: "'.$libpath.'",
        supplied: "rtmpa, mp3",
        solution: "html, flash",
        wmode: "window",
        volume: 100,
        autoplay: true,
        keyEnabled: true
    });
});
```

I am using jquery.popupWindow.js from swip.Codylindely.com which looks like this

```
jQuery('.popplayer').popupWindow({
    height:200,
    width:450,
    top:0,
    left:0
});
```

and executed with `<a href="url" class="popplayer" name="playwindow">Popup</a>`

I need an onclick.stop function somewhere but all my efforts have failed. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function to stop your main jPlayer ... like

```
function stopMainPlayer() {
 // Stop Player
}
```

then change your popup oppner link like

```
<a href="url" class="popplayer" OnClick="stopMainPlayer" name="playwindow">Popup</a>
```

you can Find the Stop player method from the jplayer
hope this will solve your porblum ..

Comment: Sorry about the very late response. I did figure the solution back in June 2013 which happened to be similar to your answer, just without the function, so your response is indeed a solution.